# Javascript runtime error: TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

I am getting this runtime error:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference
>          at $scope.typeFilter (http://*/*/*/js/controllers.js:124:9)

```
$scope.typeFilter = function(type){
    var typestring = type.Types;
    var typelist = typestring.split(", ");
}
```

Comment: `type.Types` returns `undefined` or `null` and therefore `typestring` has that value and you cannot do `typestring.split(", ")`

Comment: What should i do to avoid this error? This code should be activated only when I select the type check box, not sure why it is being called on page load

Comment: I tried to add null check for the typestring, even that didnt help

Comment: `if (!type) return;` ?

Comment: didnt work, the page is loading but its not getting all projects in the page,its empty

Comment: Okay what about `if (!type.typestring) return`? I don't understand what you mean by "it didn't work" (that's not descriptive). The error is that it is null or undefined, if you return early you shouldn't get that error.

Answer (score 0):

When you call function you might be passing argument which don't have types property. Due to this it would be null or undefined.
To avoid error you can check first if that types property has some value or not.

```
$scope.typeFilter = function(type){
  if(type.types) {
    var typestring = type.Types;
    var typelist = typestring.split(", ");
  }

}
```

Comment: That didnt work either, I get this error when i do this Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: task in tasks| filter:keyword | filter:typeFilter, Duplicate key: string: